# django - sort objects - need some help in logic

Tags: python, django

I have Topiccenter Model:

```
class TopicCenter(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField()      
  def latest_entry(self):
    latest_entries = []
    book = self.tc_books.order_by('-id')[:1]
    journal = self.tc_journals.order_by('-id')[:1]
    if book: 
        for b in book:
            if b:
                latest_entries.append(b)
    if journal: 
        for jn in journal: 
            if jn: 
                latest_entries.append(jn)
    lastone = []
    if latest_entry:            
        lastone = max(latest_entries, key = lambda x: x.added)
    return lastone
    # what to return here if lastone is empty list ?? :(
```

each topiccenter can have many books and journals. I want to get the latest entry by its `added` field.

I am sorting now topiccenters by the date of its latest entry. Now the Problem i am facing is, some topiccenters are totally empty (no book, no journals) so i dont know what to return in `latest_entry()` method if `latest_entry` is `[]` so that I can use it here like this:

```
tcss = TopicCenter.objects.all().distinct('id')  
sorter = lambda x: x.latest_entry().added
tcs = sorted(tcss, key=sorter, reverse=True)
```

at this moment i am getting `'list' object has no attribute 'added'` because one Topiccenter has neither book nor journal, so `latest_entry()` is returning `[]` which causing the error message.

can someone please help me how to solve this logic :(

Comment: You can filter out topics with no entries.

Comment: @haki but i need to show also topics which dont have any entry with entry=0

Comment: Then you need to decide the way as those empty-entry topics to be placed in the sorted result.

Comment: @okm good point thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `latest_entry()` in other places too, so just create another method `latest_added_time()` which returns `latest_entry.added` or a fake time.

```
class TopicCenter(models.Model):
    ...
    def latest_added_time(self):
        latest = self.latest_entry()
        if latest:
            return latest.added
        else:
            # returns a time to place it at the end of the sorted list
            return datetime(1, 1, 1)
```

Then, you can just sort on this new method:

```
tcss = TopicCenter.objects.all().distinct('id')  
sorter = lambda x: x.latest_added_time()
tcs = sorted(tcss, key=sorter, reverse=True)
```

If you aren't using `latest_entry()` for anything else, then you should just put this logic directly into that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing your conditions

```
if not book and not journal:
    #Action you want to perform
```

or you can see if `lastone` list is empty you can append any message there like

```
if not len(lastone):
    #Your code to append a message
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i ask here. It should be sorted properly with what i am returning if there is no entry.